# black screen after showing laptop logo ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I had a windows 10, then I have decided to work with ubuntu, after installing Ubuntu (fresh install not dual boot) I have a long booting problem, after the laptop logo shows , it takes 10 seconds on the black screen then login form shows , even after login it takes 2 or 3 seconds to load the desktop, I'm using gtx 1650 and SSD, I had the virtual machine on my windows and that ubuntu didn't take this much. how can I check what is taking this long in booting ubuntu?

by the way, I'm using an onboard graphic card too maybe it causes the problem.

Update: I have tried systemd-analyze and here is the results i dont know its good or bad for the system i have

```
Startup finished in 3.506s (kernel) + 10.048s (userspace) = 13.555s 
graphical.target reached after 10.028s in userspace
```

Comment: What happens if you do a control-alt-f1 ? do you get a login prompt?

Comment: How long does it take to run the BIOS stuff?

Comment: Just updated the question !